# replaceData() causes the table to show "No matching records found". Filters the table

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app where I want to bind new columns. The aim is to select which column and bind it using the add button. However, for some reason when I use the add button it shows "No matching records found
". I don't understand why.

Please find reproduceable code below:

```
library(shiny)

Alpha = c("a","b","c","d")
numbers = c(1,2,3,4)
extra=c("as","qw","er","he")


hi<-data.frame(Alpha,numbers,extra)


ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput('Table'),
  verbatimTextOutput('out6'),
  selectInput('in6', 'Options', colnames(hi), multiple=FALSE, selectize=TRUE),
  actionButton("add", "add column")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  output$Table = renderDT(hi, selection = 'single', editable = TRUE)
  
  
  proxy = dataTableProxy('Table')
  
  observeEvent(input$add,{
    hi2 <- hi%>%
      select(Alpha)
    hi<<-cbind(hi,hi2)
    replaceData(proxy,hi, resetPaging = FALSE)})

  output$out6 <- renderPrint(input$in6)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think it's because you added one column so you need to fully rebuild the datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use `reactiveValues` object as shown below.

```
Alpha = c("a","b","c","d")
numbers = c(1,2,3,4)
extra=c("as","qw","er","he")

hi<-data.frame(Alpha,numbers,extra)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput('Table'),
  verbatimTextOutput('out6'),
  selectInput('in6', 'Options', colnames(hi), multiple=FALSE, selectize=TRUE),
  actionButton("add", "add column")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(data=hi)

  output$Table = renderDT(rv$data, selection = 'single', editable = TRUE)

  observeEvent(input$add,{
    hi2 <- hi %>% select(input$in6)
    rv$data <- cbind(rv$data,hi2)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Table_cell_edit, {
    info = input$Table_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    v = info$value
    
    rv$data[i, j] <<- (DT::coerceValue(v, rv$data[i, j]))
  })


  output$out6 <- renderPrint(input$in6)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The reactive approach does work, however this causes the page to reset. I have the option in my shiny app to edit the table so was wondering if there is a way to either fix the `replaceData` approach or stop the reactive from resetting page? Thanks

Comment: I have the code, unfortunately same problem. Such as editing the last value refreshes the page and takes you to the top. This might be an issue with a table of many pages as it will keep refreshing it.

Comment: Your original aim was "select which column and bind it using the add button", and I think this has answered your original intent.  I am not sure I understand your issue of resetting.  It is keeping the modified columns as is, and adding additional columns based on the original dataframe.  Perhaps you should ask a separate question with appropriate data (such as, iris).